# Command-line fulltext indexing?

Tags: linux, command-line, full-text-search, code-analysis

We have a huge, old, horrible codebase that makes it nearly impossible to find things when you need it. We're working on improving it, sure... but I often find myself doing massive recursive greps to search through the contents of files to find where things are used.

Is there a tool I can use to build a fulltext index of text files in a directory and then query that from the command-line?

Prefer something that can be run in user-space and doesn't need a daemon. We have many users on our dev server, so I want something that I can search through my instance of the codebase.

Comment: Any particular language or environment?

Comment: Have you tried [`ack`](http://betterthangrep.com)? I usually find that's fast enough without needing a full text index, even on really big projects.

Comment: @GregHewgill woo, that looks interesting.  Nice domain name too :)

Answer (score 5):

I'm a big fan of "gid" (aka "id-utils"):

- http://www.gnu.org/software/idutils/manual/idutils.html

Usage is simple:

1. Install id-utils with your favorite package manager (e.g. "sudo apt-get install" or "yum")
2. "cd" to the root of a source directory and run "mkid"
3. You can use it from the command line
4. You can also use it from "vim" or any number of other tools.

Comment: PS: "ctags" is another good thing to look at: http://ctags.sourceforge.net/, http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/04/ctags-taglist-vi-vim-editor-as-sourece-code-browser/

Answer (score 2):

Russ Cox wrote [a series of articles describing how the Google Code Search algorithm worked](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp4.html). He reimplements a simplified version of the algorithm in [a set of command-line tools that can do fast regex searches over a local codebase](https://code.google.com/p/codesearch/).

An alternative is to use something like [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) to create an index of identifiers used in the code. Many editors (including Vim, which I use) can use this tags file to quickly jump to definitions of identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /path/to/project
ctags -R
```

this will create a `tags` file that vim will use, then:

```
vim -t someFunctionName
```

will open vim in the function definition!

There's also some keyboard shortcuts to make life simpler.

```
CRTL+] will jump to the definition of the method under the cursor 
CRTL+t will go back
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar need to work on a large C++ project. After surveying some tools, I found that [id-utils](http://www.gnu.org/software/idutils/) is the best choice because it's really fast on building index and searching patterns.

Based on id-utils, I made a command line tool and vim plugin to fix my need:

https://github.com/fcamel/gj

Hope it helps.