# Is there any Linux alternative of windows desktop search tool "everything"?

Tags: linux, search

Is there any alternative of popular windows desktop search "Search Everything (by Voidtools)" for linux. "Everything" is the only reason I have to stay with windows and not able to switch to linux as primary OS. I am looking for the alternative for quite sometime. I guess, someone who has already used "Everything" on windows, can only understand what I am looking for. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Having the terminal is 1000 times better than any application.

Comment: This should be posted to [Superuser](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Recoll](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/).

> Recoll finds keywords inside documents as well as file names. It can search most document formats. It can reach any storage place: files, archive members, email attachments, transparently handling decompression. One click will open the document inside a native editor or display an even quicker text preview. The software is free, open source, and licensed under the GPL.

Comment: Recoll is good but 'Everything' (on windows) is real time search & auto indexes entire hard drives in seconds. If everything does not show a file, one can be really confident that it does not exist in system. One thing that I should have mentioned that the linux alternative I am looking for, need only search file names, not the text content of the files ..

Answer (score -1):

I don't really know what is your use case.

To have a index of all file names and search for them use

```
updatedb & locate
```

to find manually things in files use ( only as example ):

```
grep <search-string> -R *

find . -type f -exec grep <search-string> {} \;
```

Indexing source code:

```
ctags & etags
```

More information about text indexing:

[Command-line fulltext indexing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814152/command-line-fulltext-indexing)

Hope this helps